# Most efficient way to operate basic calculations based on parts of other sheets? (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, performance, loops, range

My goal is to use parts of several sheets to compute basic stuff of each of the selected rows in those sheets.

The prior way to do this was to create a row with formulas manually. Let's say I have sheets: "Input1","TranslateTable", "Calculations". Then row 1 in "calculations" would have in cell A1 Input1!A1*2, B1 would have Input1!B1 / TranslateTable!D1, etcetera. The formula row would be autofilled using VBA, incrementing the rows used.This incrementing would work as all relevant rows would be sorted to the top rows in the input sheet using the VBA. Each month, all the data would be removed except for the row with the formulas, and it would be autofilled again with the amount of relevant input rows that month.

I didnt make this, and I think it's bad practise to change input data only to use it for another sheet.
Moreover, a new sheet "Input2" was added, making this method not usable. Technically, there needs to be two slightly different rows autofilled, with input2 calculations being right under the input1 calculation.

I am thinking of ways make this method more robust. Coming from Python, I'm used to calculations being very quick. So I'd figured removing the formula rows and recreating these with VBA directly. While it's working, it's extremely slow.

As I don't have much experience yet, I might not do things properly. Right now (example code), I have

```
Sub Calculations

For row_num = 2 to 20
     Sheets("Calculations").Range("A" & row_num) = Sheets("Input1").Range("B" & row_num)*5
     # and than here is the next calculation for the next cell in the row
     # again, et cetera
 
End Sub
```

Is this the right way to do this loop this? I can imagine there is a more efficient way (I know in Python there is).

I have thought of several options

1. try to make the loop more efficient
2. create rows of formula in the sheet and use vba to autofill (but then more robust than before)
3. Create formulas using VBA and then to autofill.

All help is greatly appreciated!

update: based on Bankeris' answer, I would get the following using arrays:

```
Dim RangeArray As Variant
RangeArray = Sheets("Input1").Range("A1:AZ10").Value

'and then loop calculations like this

for row_num = 2 to 15
     'my output table starts at a different row
     output_row = row_num + 2   
     ValueArrayB1Cell = RangeArray(row_num, 2)
      Range("A" & output_row) = ValueArrayB1Cell  * 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Looping through Excel Cells is very slow thing :)

Probably best way to solve this - calc everything in memory from array. Put everything into array, loop and calc and then write result in Excel.

```
Dim RangeArray As Variant
RangeArray = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5").Value

ValueArrayA1Cell = RangeArray(1, 1)
ValueArrayB2Cell = RangeArray(2, 2)
```

Comment: Hi. So to my understanding, you use arrays as an efficient way to store muliple datapoints used for calculation. I updated my post using example code of what you meant. Is this the correct way to do it?

Furthermore, I noticed it's using numbers instead of letters. Any tips for dealing with this? For instance, I would need to find the number of column AZ (and a lot of more columns). I can also imagine difficulties if columns change.